# Git checkout second remote branch

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

I run:

```
 git checkout mygithub/master
```

but for some reason, running 'git status' shows "not currently on any branch". Running:

```
 git checkout master
```

and then `git status`, says that I'm now on branch master. Now I want to switch to another branch. Running `git checkout anotherbranch` works, but `git status` says I am still on branch 'master'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `git checkout anotherbranch` produce any output?

Comment: It shows no output, no error.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`mygithub/master` is a remote branch. To create a local branch based off of that remote branch, you have to use `git checkout -b mymaster mygithub/master`. Git tries to make this easy for you: if you write `git checkout branchname`, and branchname only exists in a remote, but not locally, Git will automatically set up a local branch with `<remote>/branchname` being its parent.

Comment: So why does git checkout branchname never switch to this? Branch exists on github, I just want to merge master changes to it.

Comment: @NoBugs: `git checkout -b remotemaster mygithub/master` should create a new branch off `mygithub/master` and switch to it.

Comment: `git checkout -b otherbranch mygithub/otherbranch` works, but `git merge mygithub/master` wants to 'fast forward' and delete files from the non-master, that I want to keep.

Comment: @NoBugs: Do you want to merge `mygithub/master` into `master`, or do you want to merge `master` into `mygithub/master`? A 'fast forward' is just a special case of a merge.

Comment: Creating a new branch helped, unfortunately it was unable to push back to the original branch. `error: src refspec otherbranch does not match any.`

Comment: @NoBugs: The branch must have an upstream branch configured or a remote branch with the same name. If this isn't the case, you can always be explicit about which branch to push: `git push origin localbranch:remotebranch` (I assume in your case that's `git push mygithub otherbranch:otherbranch`)

Answer (score 15):

If you want to switch to another branch then run this command:

```
git checkout branch name
```

If you want to delete a branch then run this command:

```
git branch -D branch name
```

If you want to create a new branch then run this command:

```
git checkout -b branch
```

Answer (score -7):

If you want to checkout from master branch just run this command in your terminal

`git checkout -b BRANCH_NAME`

Comment: This will create a new branch. Reading the question, I do not think the poster wants to create a new branch.